WBEngine Error: 0x80070020 - File Access Conflict
I'm facing this issue where I can't proceed with the scheduled backups or even the manual backups.
It's returning the following error: Error in deletion of [F:\System Volume Information\MasterFileStatus.db] while pruning the target VHD: Error [0x80070020] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
I used Process Explorer during the backup process and noticed that PID 4 (system) is using this file.
I'm still using Windows Server 2012 Standard R2.
I have another disk mapped to drive E, and I use Acronis to make online backups of the files.
I also have a Lenovo storage connected via ISCSI. What I do is use robocopy to copy the files to drive F, and then back them up on this storage.
It worked 11 times before starting to give this 0x80070020 error.
Has anyone found a solution?
I tried copying the files to another drive, but without success. I also tried stopping Acronis and the antivirus, which in this case is Kaspersky for File Server, but that didn’t work either.
